# Modify items in List<T> fast

Tags: c#

I tried to make this code perform faster using Parallel.ForEach and ConcurrentBag but it's still running way to long (esp. when having in mind that in my scenario i may also be 1.000.000++):

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
for(int i = 0; i<100000;i++) {
    Point point = new Point {X = i-50000, Y = i+50000, CanDelete = false};
    points.Add(point);
}

foreach (Point point in points) {
    foreach (Point innerPoint in points) {
        if (innerPoint.CanDelete == false && (point.X - innerPoint.X) < 2) {
            innerPoint.Y = point.Y;
            point.CanDelete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe what are you trying to achieve. O(N^2) is too much even for `N >= 20000`.

Comment: If you're really going to have over a million items in your collection, you might want to start looking into better search algorithms than a nested loop... whether you spread it over a few cores with parallelization or not, it's still going to be 10^12 iterations, which is a lot (and you do realize that this will delete, for instance, a line of points no matter how long it is, as long as the points are close enough to each other, right?)

Comment: I need to get all points in _points_ with max _Y_ on each _X_ whereas _X_ can distinct from x1-x2 < tolerance. my values are just demo data. real values differ but list sizes are similar.

Comment: @Alexander: I don't see any `max Y` in your existing logic.

Comment: @matti-virkkunen do you think a points.Where(p=>point.X-p.X<2) performs faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code will perform WORSE in parallel, due to the data access patterns.

The best way to speed it up is to recognize that you don't need to consider all O(N^2) pairs of points, but only the ones having nearby X-coordinates.

First, sort the list by X-coordinate, O(N log N), then process forward and backward in the list from each point until you leave the neighborhood.  You'll need to use indexing and not `foreach`.

If your sample data, the list is already sorted.

Since your distance test is symmetric, and removes matching points from consideration, you can skip looking at earlier points.

```
for (int j = 0; j < points.Length; ++j) {
  int x1 = points[j].X;
  //for (int k = j; k >= 0 && points[k].X > x1 - 2; --k ) { /* merge points */ }
  for (int k = j + 1; k < points.Length && points[k].X < x1 + 2; ++k ) { /* merge points */ }
}
```

Not only is the complexity better, the cache behavior is far superior.  And it can be split among multiple threads with far less cache contention.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this did the trick! Very fast and correct. Thanks to all others for pointing me to the right direction also.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know exactly what do you want, but let's try.

First, when creating the List, you might want to set it's desired initial size, since you know how many items it will hold. So it does not need to grow all the time.

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>(100000);
```

Next, you could sort the list by the X property. So you would only compare each point with the points that are near it: when you find the first, forward or backward, that is too distant, you can stop comparing.